# DOCKER_REGISTRY value is not set build error

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I'm doing some experimenting with .NET Core 2.1, React/Redux, and Docker.  Without making any changes to the boilerplate ASP.NET Core with React code generated, I added Docker support to the project.

Now the project doesn't build!

When I attempt to build, I get the error 
`DOCKER_REGISTRY value is not set build error.`

Attempting to fix this, I tried changing my docker-compose file to be like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  project:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}project
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Project\Dockerfile
    environment:
      DOCKER_REGISTRY = "docker.io"
```

But, this didn't work. I assume I'm missing something pretty straightforward.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I got a little bit further by thinking that I don't have an image saved in docker.io, so why should I be trying to pull one down? I changed my docker-compose file to look like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  project:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: project\Dockerfile
```

And now the project will at least build - but it won't debug, because I now get an error on the second step of 7:

```
Service 'project' failed to build: COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder965605424\src: The system cannot find the file specified..
```

Comment: How are you passing : DOCKER_REGISTRY build argument ? The one that you are setting is environment variable and not build argument.

Comment: I saw this method online somewhere and thought it would be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Docker Compose version 1.21.2 https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5969 so you could either switch to the stable channel or update your `docker-compose.yml` to look like the following one:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  project:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}project
    build:
      context: Project
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

Comment: This one gives the same error, at least with only the dockerfile change.

Comment: I have made a minor update to the answer by adding "./" before the dockerfile at the last line

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this (change your docker-compose to pass build args rather then setting environment variables).

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  project:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/project
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Project\Dockerfile
    agrs:
      - DOCKER_REGISTRY = "docker.io"
```

Comment: When I tried this version, I got the error: "GetServicesReferences" task failed unexpectedly.